# Can't deploy python script to google cloud functions due to issue with flairnlp import

Tags: python, import, google-cloud-functions, flair

I am trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function that performs sentiment analysis on tweets using a flair nlp model. The code deploys perfectly fine without the line 'import flair' or alternatives like 'from flair import x,y,z'. As soon as I include the import statement for flair the function fails to deploy. Below is the error I get when deploying with the import statement (error is copied from Firebase logs). This is my first time posting on StackOverflow so please pardon me if the post looks ugly.

`{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.\nDetailed stack trace:\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py\", line 359, in check_or_load_user_function\n    _function_handler.load_user_function()\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py\", line 236, in load_user_function\n    spec.loader.exec_module(main_module)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/user_code/main.py\", line 5, in <module>\n    from flair import models, data\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flair/__init__.py\", line 20, in <module>\n    from . import models\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flair/models/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from .sequence_tagger_model import SequenceTagger, MultiTagger\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py\", line 21, in <module>\n    from flair.embeddings import TokenEmbeddings, StackedEmbeddings, Embeddings\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flair/embeddings/__init__.py\", line 6, in <module>\n    from .token import TokenEmbeddings\n  File \"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flair/embeddings/token.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, AutoModel, CONFIG_MAPPING, PreTrainedTokenizer\nImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)\n. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":`

And here is the script I am trying to deploy, as well as the requirements.txt file

main.py

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import flair
# or from flair import models, data

class FirestoreHandler():
    cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    db = firestore.client()
    
    def analysis_on_create(self):
            docs = self.db.collection('tweets').order_by(u'time', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING).limit(1).get()
            data = docs[0].to_dict()
            most_recent_tweet = data['full-text']
            sentiment_model = flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')
            sentence = flair.data.Sentence(str(most_recent_tweet))
            sentiment_model.predict(sentence)
            result = sentence.labels[0]
            if result.value == "POSITIVE":
                val= 1 * result.score
            else:
                val= -1 * result.score

            self.db.collection('sentiment').add({'sentiment':val,'timestamp':datetime.now()+timedelta(hours=3)}) 
            
    def add_test(self):
        self.db.collection('test3').add({"status":"success", 'timestamp':datetime.now()+timedelta(hours=3)})

def hello_firestore(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    resource_string = context.resource
    # print out the resource string that triggered the function
    print(f"Function triggered by change to: {resource_string}.")
    # now print out the entire event object
    print(str(event))
    fire = FirestoreHandler()
    fire.add_test()
    fire.analysis_on_create()
```

requirements.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version

firebase-admin==5.0.1
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
flair
```

I included the url to pytorch download because flair is built on pytorch, and the function would not deploy without the url (even when I didn't import flair in main.py). I have also tried specifying different versions for flair to no avail.

Any intuition as to what may be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated! I am new to the Google Cloud ecosystem, this being my first project. If there is any additional information I can provide please let me know.

Edit: I am deploying from the website (not using CLI)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the provided `requirements.txt` is OK for GCP cloud functions deployment. Not sure that an explicit `https` URL is going to be handled correctly...

The [Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) documentation page describes how the dependencies are to be stated - `using the pip package manager's requirements.txt file or packaging local dependencies alongside your function.`

Can you simply mention `flair` with necessary version in the `requirements.txt` file? Will it work?

In addition, the error you provided highlights that the `transformers` package is required. Can it be that some specific version is required?

====

As a side comment - I don't know your context and requirements, but I am not sure that in order to work with the Firestore from inside a cloud function all of that

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

is required, as it might be better to avoid using `serviceAccountKey.json` at all, and simply assign relevant IAM roles to the service account which is used for the given cloud function execution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately simply mentioning flair in the requirements.txt file (with or without the necessary version) does not work. For some reason it only deploys correctly when I add the pytorch url above it... but then when I try importing to main.py I get the above error. I am super confused and considering simply using a different library.